# Create a text-decoration-line on top of the text without a split in the middle

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this table row which should have a line on top with same size as the text below. I want to keep the tr the way it is without any modifications.

HTML

```
<tr>
   <td class="right_align horizontal_line_above"><b>title:</b></td>
   <td class="right_align horizontal_line_above">${value}</td>
</tr>
```

CSS

```
.right_align {
    text-align: right;
}
.horizontal_line_above{
    text-decoration-line: overline;
    text-decoration-color: blue;
    //border-top: 1px solid rgb(53, 52, 52);
}
```

I have tried two ways so far-

1. The text-decoration-line property works with a split above between the title and value  fields
2. The border-top property works without a split but goes beyond the length of the tile and value fields on both sides.

Updates after applying Ron Hillel code
[image]

Comment: `<td class="right_align horizontal_line_above><b>title:</b></td>` Did you omit " by intension after the class name?

Comment: @DreamBold not sure I understand what you said

Comment: It should be `<td class="right_align horizontal_line_above"><b>title:</b></td>`
You omitted \" character for class="....

Comment: @DreamBold that was misssed by mistake, added it now.

Comment: There's an answer to your question, is it what you need? Your current code looks like this https://codepen.io/dreambold/pen/OJZwgBm

Comment: @DreamBold Thats exactly how my current code looks, but the line does not appear there.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.right_align {
    text-align: right;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(53, 52, 52);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="right_align horizontal_line_above"><b>title:</b></td>
    <td class="right_align horizontal_line_above">${value}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ron Hillel, this does not work, I have attached a snip to my original post after makingchanges